# How do I prevent loading duplicate items from the same MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table "`news`" with a field called "`keyword`". I fetch different sections on my website based on this. As for example:

For technology section I use:

```
SELECT * from news where keyword like '%tech%'
```

For recent articles section I use:

```
SELECT * from news
```

Now the problem is that when both of these sections are loaded, I see repeating articles. How do I prevent this prom happening?

Comment: Never use `SELECT *`.

Comment: @Kermit ... unless of course you intend to select all columns, such as for debugging or dynamically populating objects with all column data.  "Never" is a bit strong, but yes I generally agree with you.

Comment: What can I do instead Kermit? Suggestions please. Thank you.

Comment: Personally, I would leave it as is. If an artlicle has multiple subjects why wouldn't you want it to show up in both categories?

Comment: Brad, yes I SELECT all data from my database to populate my page. As for example, my recent section uses the most recent data from the table. technology section only pulls the technology tagged data. But the problem is there are repeating items.

Comment: I agree with @Adelphia but if you really don't want that, the obvious solution would be to modify the second query with `where keyword not like '%tech%'`

Comment: At some point you'll need to split that into a one-to-many relationship, but for now that should work.

Comment: Adelphia, the problem is the sections are in the landing page. Apparently, when people see duplicates, they tend to distrust my website. I personally have never seen any blog with repeating content on different sections.

Comment: Tadman, could you please elaborate how I can implement your method? Right now, this problem seems to me as a major one. So I require an easy solution to this.

Comment: @Brad You would approach each of those scenarios differently. The *never* may have been a bit strong, but it's not best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple solution:

First create an array with all your topics:

```
$topics = array(
    "home",
    "tech",
    "cake",
    "animals",
    "gynecologogy",
    "recipes"
);
```

Then add this function on your page somewhere which will create the SQL query for you:

```
function makeQuery($topic, $topics){
    $q = "SELECT * from news where keyword like '%".$topic."%' AND ";
    foreach($topics as $t){
        if($t == $topic){
            continue;
        }
        $q .= "keyword NOT LIKE '%".$t."%' AND ";
    }
    $q = rtrim($q, " AND ");
    return $q;
}
```

Then you can use the function to create your query. So for example, if you're still using the (deprecated, yes I know) `mysql_*` functions, you could just use the function as your query, like so:

```
$Q = mysql_query(makeQuery("tech", $topics));
```

**USING A SINGLE QUERY:**

If you want to sort them from a single query, you could use something like this. This is just an example. You'll have to modify the code to fit your needs.

```
$articles = array();
$Q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `news`");
while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($Q)){
    if(strpos($res['news'], 'tech') !== false){
        $articles['tech'] = $res;
    }
}
```

Comment: The last line is just an example. It should still work no matter what API you use. If it works the way you want please remember to hit the check mark! :) Godspeed.

Comment: @Susan I posted a quick example of another way you could do it using a single query. I recommend using the first example though as it is more efficient. If you're having trouble with it post the error you got I'll help you debug it.

Comment: Okay, so I tried using the first example, and I'm getting this error: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/*****/public_html/*****.php on line 60

Comment: @Susan Sorry, I forgot about the scope issue. You'll have to either put the array inside of the function or pass it into the function like I show in my edit.

Comment: Still facing the same problem. And one more problem I'm now facing is this "Missing argument 2 for makeQuery()". I'm trying your second example now.

Comment: @Susan I updated my answer in two place, you have to add the second parameter like I posted above: `mysql_query(makeQuery("tech", $topics));`

Answer (score 1):

Try

`SELECT * from news where not exists (SELECT * from news where keyword like '%tech%')`

So you shold get no nwes with subject tech in the second result

Comment: Should this be the correct parameter? 
`SELECT DISTINCT * FROM news where NOT EXISTS $recent keyword like '%tech%'`
Here `$recent = SELECT * from news`

Comment: That won't work @Susan because you're using multiple queries for each topic. The `DISTiNCT` keyword will only help if you get all your topics from a single query.

Comment: Is there any easier way to implement this using a single query, maybe using a variable or something? I cannot get your function to work, that you mentioned in the previous answer. Sorry. I'm just a noob.

Comment: @Susan if you get it from a single query you can sort them thru PHP instead of SQL. If you do it that way you don't need a fancy query. A simple `SELECT * FROM news` will work. I'll post an update to my answer with an example.